# Not able to get url parameter while unit testing Django's rest api using APIRequestFactory

Tags: python, django, rest

I have created a rest api using Django's `rest_framework`. It's created using class based view.

**views.py**

```
import logging
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.response import Response

from handlers.product import get_data

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class ProductView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, SessionAuthentication)

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            product_id = kwargs['product_id']
            response = get_data(product_id)
            return Response(response)
        except KeyError as key:
            log.exception(key)
            return Response({'error_msg': '{} is required'.format(key)}, status=400)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^product/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/data/$', ProductView.as_view(), name='product'),
```

And this is what I have tried,

```
import pytest
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from mixer.backend.django import mixer
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory

from views import *

pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db


@pytest.fixture()
def token():
    user = mixer.blend(User)
    return Token.objects.create(user=user)


class TestProductView:

    def test_get_data(self, token):
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        request = factory.get('/product/100230/data/', HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token {}'.format(token))
        response = ProductView.as_view()(request)
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

My test fails because I get an exception,

```
KeyError: 'product_id'
```

But when I run my app and request the api from browser it takes the product_id from the url.

Please note that I really have to use `kwargs` in `get` api method because later I want to make get_data generic and pass all the url params and query params to it.

---

### Update (29/01/2018)

Django test client (`django.test.Client`) came to the rescue!

I have started using it instead of `RequestFactory` whenever I have url params. I am not sure if I should put that as answer on this post.

Answer (score 0):

The RequestFactory provides a way to generate a request instance that can be used as the first argument to any view. 'request' in the view below:

```
def view(request, url_parameter):
    ...
```

django.test.Client will simulate GET and POST requests on a URL and observes the response – everything from low-level HTTP (result headers and status codes) to page content.

That is straight from the docs. But I'll provide the answer for anyone who looks here the future.

```
django.test.Client #Simulate 'GET' and 'POST' sides.
```